# iPhone: How to get Video file binary when using ALAssetsLibrary enumeration?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to access iPhone's photo album gallery through ALAssetsLibrary. I am successful accessing the photo album and get the asset URL of each images on the device. My testing is, after getting all the images, uploading to my web server is also working well.
I am also trying to get the video file and do the same process, i.e. upload video file to my server. Here is the issue, i don't know how to access video pointer binary like how i did for images using UIImageJPEGRepresentation, and send to my HTTP code?

```
-(void) assetsEmumeration {


void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
            [assetArray addObject:result];
            // get image url
            NSURL *url = [[result defaultRepresentation] url];
            NSString *urlInStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];

            NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation ([UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]], 90);

            HttpUpload (imgData);
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
    {

        if(group != nil) {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
        [self.activity stopAnimating];
        [self.activity setHidden:YES];
    };
    assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                         }];
    assetArray = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
```

}

Could someone came across this to solve, please guide me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the raw bytes using ALAssetRepresentation's [`getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:) method, something like this:

```
uint8_t *bytes = malloc([representation size]);
NSError *error = nil;
NSUInteger length = [representation getBytes:bytes fromOffset:0 length:[representation size] error:&error];
```