# iOS ALAssetsLibrary and NSFileHandle reading file contents

Tags: ios, nsfilehandle, assetslibrary

I want to read the contents of an assets library file in iOS

`NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromUrl` using the asset `defaultRepresentation` url seems to always return `0x0`...

I'll keep looking for a solution in the mean time.

EDIT:

Looks like the answer from  [Anomie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592612/iphone-how-to-get-video-file-binary-when-using-alassetslibrary-enumeration) might be what I want:

`NSUInteger length = [representation getBytes:bytes fromOffset:0 length:[representation size] error:&error];`

Comment: Anomie's answer will probably work with small videos, but if you are dealing with larger videos you will probably have to copy out by chunks. See my answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For larger files you probably want to copy out via a loop to read X bytes in chunks, otherwise you are liable to exhaust the on-device memory.

```
NSUInteger chunkSize = 100 * 1024;
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(uint8_t));

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
NSUInteger length = [rep size];

NSFileHandle *file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: tempFile] retain];

if(file == nil) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tempFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:tempFile] retain];
}

NSUInteger offset = 0;
do {
    NSUInteger bytesCopied = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:chunkSize error:nil];
    offset += bytesCopied;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:bytesCopied];
    [file writeData:data];
    [data release];
    } while (offset < length);

[file closeFile];
[file release];
free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```

Comment: @Adam - I wanted to edit the code such that the horizontal bar does not get shown off (so that I can look at the code at one shot instead of scrolling left and right), so I put some next-line characters in some loc earlier. :) But it should not be too much of inconvenience I guess. :) I wish SO would make the code-section something like XCode editor :) Thanks anyways for further edit.

Comment: @Viren: I'm not sure what happened there, but my guess is that I saw the previous version of the answer that had part of the code not indented properly (and thus not marked as code), and when I corrected that, it stomped on your second edit.